# How to get updated input field value on change using formValueSelector in redux-form

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I'm using `redux-form` and `formValueSelector` to get input values from fields. I want to get value on change, but `@@redux-form/CHANGE` action is called after my function called on `onChange`. So I get not updated value. My code:

```
export class PersonFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  filterByName = (event, searchName) => {
    //here searchName is getting old value
    store.dispatch({type: 'PERSON_FILTER_BY_NAME', payload: {name: searchName}});
  };


  render() {
    const {
      searchName
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className="person person--filter" onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.filterByName(e, searchName)
      }}>
        <Field
          onChange={e => {
            this.filterByName(e, searchName)
          }}
          className="person__input" icon="search"
          name="searchName" component={renderField} type="text"
          placeholder="Name"/>

      </form>
    );
  }
}



PersonFilter = reduxForm({
  form: 'filter',
  initialValues: {
    searchName: store.getState().personsFilterReducer.filterByName
  }

})(PersonFilter);

const selector = formValueSelector('filter');

PersonFilter = connect(state => {
  const searchName = selector(state, 'searchName');
  return {
    searchName
  }
})(PersonFilter);
```

and wrapper component:

```
class Persons extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PersonFilter/>
      </div>  
    };    
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any parent component ?

Comment: @Aaqib yes, wrapper for components

Comment: where is wrapper component code

Comment: @Aaqib updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just passing  onChange to the action you should  `setState`, firstly  initialise the state `this.state` inside the wrapper component constructor and make sure you pass **props** to the constructor as well , and then setting a state inside onChange function `this.setState` and binding it.
Something like this:

Wrapper Component

```
class Persons extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {} 
    }
    onChange(field, value) {   
        this.setState({[field]: value});
    }
    render () {
        return <PersonFilter onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
    }
}
```

And inside your `PersonFilter` component make a function `onFieldChange` which will pass the reference to the function `onChange` inside wrapper component to set the state `this.setState`

```
export class PersonFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

    onFieldChange(event) {
        const changeName = event.target.name;
        const changeValue = event.target.value;
        this.props.onChange(fieldName, fieldValue);
    }
```

and then finally

```
     <Field
      onChange={this.onFieldChange.bind(this)}
      className="person__input" icon="search"
      name="searchName" component={renderField} type="text"
      placeholder="Name"/>
```